# How to prevent AutoPano from splitting my panorama?

Tags: panorama, image-stitching

I was trying to stitch 8 images and got the following picture:

[image]

I.e., AutoPano decided picutres are not connected.

How do I force AutoPano to connect them?

**UPDATE**

I have found the following setting:

[image]

After which I got the following picture:

[image]

I.e. it dropped all images into a heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Autopano [FAQ](http://www.kolor.com/wiki-en/action/view/Autopano_-_Common_cases_that_don%27t_stitch_automatically_-_Low_details) mentions a similar case and the solution: in your case, it should be enough to tick the option `force every image to be in one panorama`.

Comment: Literally, this is the answer, so I am selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first mistake was shooting without enough overlap. The program needs distinct features it can match between the two frames. In the case of the roof: you don't have the point of the roof in both images.  Ideally, you should be overlapping frames by about ⅓ of the frame.  The less overlap you have, the less information a stitching program has to work with to line up and connect the images.

Kolar has a page of common stitching errors and how to fix them. Like most panorama stitching programs, you can [manually position the problematic member image](http://www.kolor.com/wiki-en/action/view/Autopano_-_Common_cases_that_don't_stitch_automatically_-_Low_details#Step_3:_How_to_fix_it).  Or, you can [manually define control points, the points](http://www.kolor.com/wiki-en/action/view/Autopano_Giga_-_Panorama_Editor_-_Control_Points_Editor#CONTROL_POINTS_EDITOR_WINDOW) at which the images join.

Comment: So, how to manually move the second group of images, relative to first one? This is the question.

Comment: Start over with a new project would be my guess. I'm not an Autopano user--I use PTGui, so I can't give you steps.

Comment: How to do this in PTGui? I remember I had similar problems with it.

Comment: @Dims If you have a separate question, ask it as a separate question. but honestly, the Autostitch step-by-step how-tos are in the links in my answer, which is why I put them there.